# Login with AsyncTask or Service?

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask

I need to implement login functionality. The thing is, should I use an asynctask or service to connect to my server? I have read that asynctask must be use on operations that won't take more than 1 or 2 seconds. But networks operations can take longer and therefore my asynctask can be killed by the operative system if any process blocks my current activity.
Help, please!

Comment: `I have read that asynctask must be use on operations that won't take more than 1 or 2 seconds.` that's foolish. use asynctask for anything that can't be called on the UI Thread, keeping in mind that your asynctask is linked to the lifecycle of the surrounding context. `my asynctask can be killed by the operative system if any process blocks my current activity`  that's plain wrong. your asynctaks will stop if the context stops (in your case, your activity).

Comment: If an incoming call appear, wouldn't my activity get blocked? and therefore the context will stop?

Comment: Yes. also if you rotate the device, turn off the screen, press the home button...

Comment: but checking a login should be a single server call, and shouldn't take more than a few hundreds of milliseconds. If the activity is paused or stopped meanwhile, you can always restart when the activity is back.

Comment: So, how can I prevent those scenarios?

Comment: You don't really need to. It all goes very fast, and if the user is interrupted by a phone call, just restart the server call when the activity is restarted. (and show a progress dialog). The user probably won't even notice something happened. (in most cases).

Comment: OK, I got it. Thank you very much!

Comment: then you can go into much more complicated stuff, but that's more work, and not necessarily worth it in the first stages of the development of an app.